# itext romaneio pdf para impressora não fiscal

Tags: java, impressão, itext

estou desenvolvendo um romaneio para separação de pedidos em java com itext, está praticamente pronto, porém o padrão de documento está como A4, e o ideal seria para o padrão de impressoras não fiscais, alguém poderia dar uma força de como passo converter para 40 colunas?

Comment: Já descobri a solução, o itext funciona com pontos, calculei qual seria a medida em ponto para a minha necessidade e deu certo. 1 pol = 24,5mm = 72 pontos.
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(227, 842);
     Document pdf = new Document(pagesize, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);